# How to implement Swipe previous or next item in Horizontal Recycler view

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have seen so many examples, but I haven't found any swipable recycler view in horizontal mode.

I want to create recycler view whose item covers whole screen, and i want to swipe to next item, don't want to scroll because it stuck in the middle of two items.

There is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.35">

            <ImageView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:maxWidth="340dp"
                android:minWidth="300dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/row_image"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                android:id="@+id/row_status"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/PrimaryColor"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_designcode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:text="Design Code"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_outcode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text="Outlet Code"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img_attach"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_attachment"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_KaragirCode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text="Karagir Code"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_DiaCrt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_weight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_cc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyt_hotperl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_hot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_pearl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyt_ODD"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_orderdeldate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_orderno"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                    android:text=""
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btnUrgent"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                    android:background="@color/colorUrgent"
                    android:text="Urgent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/appcard_textSize"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use another component for that. RecyclerView is extending listView, that intends to scroll most of the time. But there are some other component that can swipe.